# VM from VMware Fusion to VMware Player, some questions

Tags: linux, centos, vmware-fusion

I want to install the VMware player on a Linux based host (CentOS 5.4).

questiion 1: Do i need a graphical surface like KDE or is it possible to run the VM (Windows XP Professional) on the text based Linux?

question 2: is it possible to transfere a VM created with VMware Fusion to the up listed CentOS 5 Host?

question 3: If yes, how can i do this?

I Hope someone can help me...

Best regards

Tito...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think there is support to run player without a graphical frontend.
2. Depends on the version. New virtual machines should transfer smoothly. For old machines you might need to convert it first. There is a tool to convert virtual images, you can find it on the vmware homepages.
3. Just move the data files over and import them in Player.